# Build for different library versions with SBT

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I am trying to build my Scala source code with SBT targeting **same** Scala version but different versions of libraries. My questions are:

1. Does SBT support this? (seems unlikely)
2. If not, is there a way to achieve this without messing the build script too much?

---

Details:
I am building for clusters with different versions of Spark and other libraries. This seems to be a common user case in such a scenario.

Possible solutions I have found:

1. Use different minor versions of Scala, then dispatch different versions of library with cross-building. Very hackish.
2. Use dummy directories for multiple projects, redirecting their source paths to the real source directory. This seems most promising but I have not tried it yet.

Comment: you didn't get a better answer since then I guess ?

Answer (score 0):

No sbt does not support this, but if you want to do that then you can use shading.
like if I want to use two different versions of guava that was supported by  two different libraries then use guava shading like:

```
    assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
     ShadeRule.rename("com.google.guava**" -> "shadeio.@1").inAll
    )
```